# Xcode Object Library Objects not in Swift

Tags: xcode

I tried to pull a tableview controller from the object library and opened up the assistant editor, it showed that the tableview controller pulled was in Object C but Swift.  I want objects (controller) to be in Swift, does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is showing you Objective-C?  If you're creating a controller subclass, you can write it in the language you choose.

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the `UITableViewController` content class. That class is obviously in Objective-C. The `UITableViewController` belongs to `UIKit` framework and that framework is written in Objective-C.

You can create a new class in `File -> New -> File -> Source -> Cocoa Touch Class`. Then you have tu subclass of `UITableViewController`.

[image]

After that, you have to select your `UITableViewController` from your Storyboard and set the class on the Identity Inspector.

[image]

Then, on the assistant editor if you have selected automatic file selection, you are going to see your custom `UITableViewController`.

Most of the frameworks like `UIKit` still written in Objective-C. So if you have created a Swift project, the main objects of the library object will be in Objective-C